# Android - AsyncTask for continuous thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Is it safe to use an `AsyncTask` class object without ever using `get`, to create a constantly running thread? (etc. involving a `while` loop)

Comment: "without ever using get" You almost never want to use `get()`. It is a blocking call meaning that your UI will be unresponsive until the task returns.

Comment: Yes, but normally you want to call it sometime after, no? (I'm still a beginner)

Comment: No. I've never needed it. I'm sure it has its uses but I haven't come across any. Otherwise, it isn't asynchronous. The point is to let it run in the background while the rest of your UI is functional then use a call back in `onPostExecute()` to update whatever you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) :

> AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.

So, no: it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna run a long process or need the task run in background, you need a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) instead an AsyncTask.